# Overriding Library Functions

Tags: haskell, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am trying to use [Crypto.PubKey.ECIES](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-PubKey-ECIES.html) library that call `curveGenerateKeyPair` function from [Crypto.ECC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.21/docs/src/Crypto-ECC.html)  library and [Crypto.ECC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.21/docs/src/Crypto-ECC.html) uses [Crypto.PubKey.ECC.P256](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-PubKey-ECC-P256.html) for  `scalarGenerate` function, how can i modify  this `scalarGenerate` function without modifying all those libraries?, is there any other way to do this?

Basically, I want to modify `scalarGenerate` function of [Crypto.PubKey.ECC.P256](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-PubKey-ECC-P256.html)  library (to use randomByteString generation of [Raaz](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/raaz-0.2.0/docs/Raaz-Random.html) library),
so that will affect the output of `deriveEncrypt` function from [Crypto.PubKey.ECIES](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-PubKey-ECIES.html) library

I'm using curve type as `curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_X25519`

Comment: What curve type are you using with `deriveEncrypt`? You almost certainly need to define your own curve type, but without concrete details it's awfully hard to say.

Comment: @dfeuer  `curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_X25519`

Comment: And finally you get to the point. But why is it in a comment? It's an essential piece of the question!

Comment: Added in question

Comment: I've modified my answer to match your modified question.

Answer (score 1):

`deriveEncrypt` uses `curveGenerateKeyPair` for the relevant curve. I don't see anything about `scalarGenerate` there. The `EllipticCurve` instance for `Curve_X25519` defines

```
curveGenerateKeyPair _ = do
    s <- X25519.generateSecretKey
    return $ KeyPair (X25519.toPublic s) s
```

If you want to generate `X25519` keypairs some other way, you'll have to define your own version of the `Curve_X25519` type, copy the `EllipticCurve` and `EllipticCurveDH` instances for `Curve_X25519` type to make instances for your type, but replace the definition of `curveGenerateKeyPair` with your own.

Comment: Yeh we can do this if 'A' is just calling 'B' library then we can make instance of 'B' and override it, but  if 'A' is calling 'B' , 'B' is calling 'C', can we override instance of 'C'  from 'A'?

Comment: @MaheshUligade, it's really hard to come up with a concrete answer when the question is vague. Can you edit your question to explain more concretely and in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry to be vague. Basically, I want to modify the random seed generation in `scalarGenerate` function of `Crypto.PubKey.ECC.P256` , so that will effect in `curveGenerateKeyPair`  in `Crypto.PubKey.ECIES`

Comment: @MaheshUligade, that's still vague. Please improve your question instead of creating a long thread in the comments.

Comment: Thanks  I have done it some other way, I am upvoting your answer

Comment: @MaheshUligade, you should post your own answer to explain how you did it.